# How to deploy document images from sandbox to production org

Tags: deployment

Hii I have a requirement to deploy email templates from the sandbox to the production org .

The email templates have some images associated with them.

In the sandbox org these images are in the documents folder .Since these images are not static resources (hence, they are not meta data) ,they cannot be deployed using change sets

If I manually download these images from the sandbox org and then upload them in the production org then I have to replace each and every links in the email templates.

Is there any other way apart from manually downloading then uploading that I can deploy these images from sandbox to the production org

Please guide me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Add images in static resource, refer them in template. And then simply move templates and static resource to prod.

Comment: Hi @RohitMourya I am using custom email templates. Is it possible to refer static resources in Custom email templates?

Comment: Refer this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Why-images-stored-as-static-resources-cannot-be-seen-in-emails-sent-using-VF-email-templates-1327108316482&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: I exactly did the same way mentioned in the above link. So , if I manually upload the images in the production org I will alsso have to manually change in the document id and organization id of the following markup: "<apex:image id="theImage" value="https://c.<instance>.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=<document_id>&oid=<organization_id>" width="200" height="200"/>
"